# Unable to click anchor tags inside onClick() event drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, slidetoggle

I have this HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="parent_menu">
        <ul class="child-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        </ul>

    </li>
</ul>
```

The following Jquery to show the drop down when hover over parent:

```
$('.parent_menu').on('touchstart click', function(e){
                e.stopPropagation(); 
                e.preventDefault();

                $(".child-menu", this).slideToggle(400); 

            }       
        );
```

What happens here is, the drop down menu is showing if I click on the parent menu. But I am unable to click on the anchor tag of the child menu items (like Link 1, Link 2, etc..) in the drop down list. I think this is due to the `slideToggle()` or `onClick()` used above. How can I fix it so the child menu links are clickable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are these here for a reason?

```
e.stopPropagation(); 
e.preventDefault();
```

`preventDefault()` will kill your anchors. If you don't need them, remove them.

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Qv8hn

---

Here's how you'd use `stopPropagation()` to prevent your links from toggling the menu:

```
$('.parent_menu').on('touchstart click', function (e) {
    $(".child-menu", this).slideToggle(400);
}).find('a').on('touchstart click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Qv8hn/1

Comment: You are right. When I remove `e.preventDefault();`, the anchors are clickable. It works fine im desktop. But without `e.preventDefault();`. the drop down gets toggled down and goes up straight away in ipads and touch screen devices. What can I do for touch devices?

Comment: See my recent update. Also, you may not even need `touchstart`. Those devices know what a click is, and it's possible that it's toggling twice for that reason.

Comment: perfect isherwood. You were spot on. It was the `touchstart` that was causing that issue without `e.preventDefault();`. I removed it and like you said it worked in touchscreen too. The anchor also works now. Thank you so much. I was stuck on this for a few hours. You helped heaps. Cheers!

Comment: And I dont think I would even need `e.stopPropagation();` after you pointed out. ;)

Comment: Only if you care that the menu slides up as you're leaving the page. It's only slightly weird. :-)